# To call C# Function from Javascript in Web apps

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi i wanted to call a C# function through javascript code.

For Eg: i have C# function which is in aspx.cs page

```
public void setValue()
{
   lblMsg.Text = "hello";
   ....
   .....  
}
```

from javascript i need to call this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible directly indeed. If you are using Web Forms you can have a C# button handler which will change text of your label in server side and then you can call the _doPostBack function for that handler.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have to do as postback, either complete or partial. Use AJAX (UpdatePanel)